# How to get visitor location ( country, state and city ) using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, geolocation

I want to implement this in ASP.NET. I don't have any idea about how to do so, unfortunately.

Comment: You can only get an approximate location, and it may be incorrect.

Comment: Same. Sorry for the concurrent edit! Feel free to rollback over me.

Answer (score 10):

Here how it is done in asp.net

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

Get a copy of IP adress database by location here

http://www.maxmind.com/

Comment: Should be Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] in C#

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/)? You will get more than what you need. Alternatively you can get the client's ip and use service like [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/developers.aspx) to get the location.

Check this similar question as well. [finding clients location in asp.net page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238180/finding-clients-location-in-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 4):

by using

```
string userHost = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userHost) || 
    String.Compare(userHost, "unknown", true) == 0)
{
    userHost = Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

you will get users ip address . Based on this ip address you can find out visitor location details by calling some [webservice](http://www.webservicex.net/WCF/default.aspx) .

Comment: That server variable is only available if your webserver is behind a proxy or some kind of network device.

Comment: I believe that was the whole point of his logic, to check for that, and then fall back on the user host address if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few free web services out there which provide IP-to-location services. For instance:

http://freegeoip.net/
http://www.hostip.info/
http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Answer (score 2):

[IPAddressExtensions](http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/) is a free codeplex class library if all you just want is the Country the IP is located from.

Answer (score 2):

First, get the IP address of the visitor using Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR").
Bear in mind that the visitor could be using a proxy server in which case the IP address may not be their actual IP address. For the proxy case, you can check if Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") contains a value. This will be the actual IP address if the proxy server is not an anonymous proxy server.

Then you have 2 options, using a web service or querying data from your own database. Either way, you will need data which can match an IP address of the visitor to their country, state and city.

Answer (score 1):

Using the geolocation API at ipStack (https://ipstack.com), I've used the following:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>         $.ajax({
>             'url': 'https://www.freegeoip.net/json/@(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress)',
>             'type': 'GET',
>             'success': function(data) {
>                 // for example
>                 if (data.country_code === "GB") {
>                     ... further logic here
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>     });
> </script>
> ```

It returns a lot of useful information, e.g.:

```
{
  "ip": "134.201.250.155",
  "hostname": "134.201.250.155",
  "type": "ipv4",
  "continent_code": "NA",
  "continent_name": "North America",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "region_code": "CA",
  "region_name": "California",
  "city": "Los Angeles",
  "zip": "90013",
  "latitude": 34.0453,
  "longitude": -118.2413,
  "location": {
    "geoname_id": 5368361,
    "capital": "Washington D.C.",
    "languages": [
        {
          "code": "en",
          "name": "English",
          "native": "English"
        }
    ],
    "country_flag": "https://assets.ipstack.com/images/assets/flags_svg/us.svg",
    "country_flag_emoji": "",
    "country_flag_emoji_unicode": "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8",
    "calling_code": "1",
    "is_eu": false
  },
  "time_zone": {
    "id": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "current_time": "2018-03-29T07:35:08-07:00",
    "gmt_offset": -25200,
    "code": "PDT",
    "is_daylight_saving": true
  },
  "currency": {
    "code": "USD",
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "plural": "US dollars",
    "symbol": "$",
    "symbol_native": "$"
  },
  "connection": {
    "asn": 25876,
    "isp": "Los Angeles Department of Water & Power"
  },
  "security": {
    "is_proxy": false,
    "proxy_type": null,
    "is_crawler": false,
    "crawler_name": null,
    "crawler_type": null,
    "is_tor": false,
    "threat_level": "low",
    "threat_types": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the client IP and find the location of IP using any IP to geo location Mapping service.