# How get user location using user IP Address?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get visitor location ( country, state and city ) using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409108/how-to-get-visitor-location-country-state-and-city-using-asp-net)

How get user location using user IP address using asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=325