# How to Get the User Location Country

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do i get the User`s Location (Country) in Asp.Net MVC from Request?

Comment: Have you got a Country property in your model? Do you want to determine it based on the user agent? Do you want an IP lookup? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409108/how-to-get-visitor-location-country-state-and-city-using-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You may try to do a lookup by IP. But it's not 100% guaranteed result.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.Browser.UserLanguages[0]
```