# Redirect page similar google domain name change country wise

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to create website default page country wise. 
Similar to google
When google open in **Pakistan** is auto redirect to https://www.google.com.pk
If `UK` auto redirect to https://www.google.co.uk
How to do this using asp.net c# web form?
Remember that I want this at asp.net c# web form page to page 
Not domain to domain

Comment: Idea is to detect the country then redirect the user to the desired page. This might be some help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17588358/4720652

Comment: 1. Have you actually registered all those domains? You don't get them automatically. You have to purchase each one.

Comment: 2. Do you have a Geo-Location service, to know where your user is coming from? Google has to look up this information based on IP address, routing information, or which CDN processes the request, and doesn't always get it right.