# Currency formatting language?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, format

I am using a GridView and I need to show the currency in Arabic culture so I used this code which is working very well,

DataFormatString="{0:c}"

The results will be like this : د.ك.‏ 55.000
Now what I want is to change it like this :   55.000 K.D ???

Comment: Have you tried `DataFormatString = "{0:0.000} K.D."`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `DataFormatString = "{0:0.000} K.D."`?

[As shown in this example.](http://ideone.com/T0CZP)

Comment: well, this will not solve the whole problem!!

because the website is multilingual and I want to see the currency in Arabic format like this "  د.ك.‏ 55.000"   and in the English like this "55.000 K.D" 

your way will make English only all the time

Comment: Errm you kind of left that fact out of your original question! :) Well, on what basis are you going to determine which country the user is viewing your site from? Provided you can determine this correctly, `Select Case` on their location. Perhaps a separate question in itself...

Comment: Presumably you will also need to change text on your site from Arabic to English too? You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238180/finding-clients-location-in-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: it's only two languages Arabic and English, 

"ar-KW" and "en-US" but the currency should be KW only not USD

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3827/discussion-between-hajjaj-and-el-ronnoco)